# What effects cancel the "Frozen" state

Tags: xcom-2

If an enemy is frozen, I know of several effects that cancel this effect (the frozen turn time ending is obvious):

- Incendiary Bomb (Also other types of fire?)
- Andromedon state change ("killing" first state while frozen)
- Explosions (Always? What type?)

So: What other effects cancel the "frozen" state?

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know:

- If you hit a Dominate or Insanity (and get Mind Control), then they will be unfrozen, but this is more of a help.
- Killing the first stage of an Andromedon *does* mean that the shell won't be frozen, but it's important to note that killing the first stage is a kill for *all intents and purposes*. The shell is just spawned immediately afterwards, and the first stage doesn't drop a corpse, like, say, a Neonate Viper or Derelict MEC. So it's less "after the first stage, it thaws" and more "a completely different enemy spawns that isn't frozen".
- On that note, killing an enemy does *technically* remove freeze effects, but that never matters. Psi zombies are another "completely different enemy" thing, just with the corresponding sprite. (And, funnily enough, if you reload a save with psi zombies, they'll all be reset to the same generic soldier sprite.)
- The Dying Explosion ability, at the beginning of the unit's turn. The Dying Explosion ability is only possessed by the Sectopod and Gatekeeper, but I assume that it would still work if you modded it onto an ADVENT trooper or something.

  - Update: I'm not entirely sure yet whether this applies to War of the Chosen's ADVENT Purifiers, which explode upon death.
- Frag grenades and plasma grenades don't seem to unfreeze enemies.